# Hibernate, get foreign id without loading associated entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Simple example:

mappings:

```
@Entity
public class City {
    @Id@GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Country country;
...


@Entity
public class Country {
    @Id@GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
...
```

usage:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from City");
List<?> cities = query.list();
for (Object cityObj : cities) {
    City city = (City) cityObj;
    System.out.printf("City: %s %s%n", city.getId(), city.getName());
    Country country = city.getCountry();
    System.out.println("Country retrieved");
    Integer countryId = country.getId();
    System.out.printf("Country id: %s%n", countryId);
}
```

here's output:

```
Hibernate: select city0_.id as id0_, city0_.country_id as country3_0_, city0_.name as name0_ from City city0_
City: 1 Astana
Country retrieved
Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_0_, country0_.name as name1_0_ from Country country0_ where country0_.id=?
Country id: 1
City: 2 Almaty
Country retrieved
Country id: 1
City: 3 Omsk
Country retrieved
Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_0_, country0_.name as name1_0_ from Country country0_ where country0_.id=?
Country id: 2
```

Now that's a strange behavior. I can get Country object (probably some proxy) and Hibernate didn't issue any additional SQL queries yet. But when I call country.getId() – hibernate issues SQL query to load full country object. It's obvious that Hibernate knows country.id value so I expected that hibernate will just return that id without any additional SQL queries. But it does not.

The problem is - I don't need that entire entity. I only need id and I don't want that separate SQL query (or JOIN query if I set FetchType.EAGER).

Comment: Maybe this is how mapping in hibernate works fetching all child record entities when querying for only one entity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you will have have to change your `Country` entity like below.Add `AccessType` annotation on the Id field.

```
@Entity
    public class Country {
        @Id@GeneratedValue@AccessType("property")
        private Integer id;

        private String name;
```

Faced similar problem,and followed this article:-
[Accessor Type Annotation](http://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/hibernate_lazy_field_access_annotations.shtml)

Comment: Thanks. I debugged hibernate code and found that if I set @Id annotation on getId method instead of id property, it'll work too. Strange behavior, but that's probably how hibernate works.

Comment: Note: When using @AccessType, a public setter for id is also required, otherwise you'll get a ton of exceptions when trying to load entities.

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin I've used this without a setter and it works fine :) Perhaps its been fixed since.

Answer (score 1):

So correct JPA-only standard solution will be:

```
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id @GeneratedValue @Access(PROPERTY)
    private Integer id;
```

Comment: I don't think the Access annotation is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add to @RE350's answer.

In Hibernate 5.2.15, if you are using `CriteriaQuery`. Then this can be done easily without the need of the `@AccessType` annotation.(which has been deprecated in favor of `@AttributeAccessor`).

```
final CriteriaBuilder cb = criteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<City> query = criteriaQuery();

final Root<City> q = query.from(City.class);
final Path<Integer> uid = q.get("country").get("id"); // Note this!!
```

**Note**:
You can also fetch country like this in which case, it will actually join the table.

```
final Path<Integer> uid = q.join("country").get("id");
```

Update:

In the case of a ManyToMany join however, this does not seem to be easy, unless you have an entity to model the ManyToMany table.

Comment: doing q.get("country").get("id"); will still fetch the full country object